# The source directory / does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: software-installation, opencv

I was trying to install opencv. And I followed the steps given in [this link](http://www.codebind.com/cpp-tutorial/install-opencv-ubuntu-cpp/).
But, after cloning the directories `opencv.git` and `opencv_contrib.git` and running the command:

```
cmake -D BUILD_TIFF=ON -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D ENABLE_AVX=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D WITH_IPP=OFF -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_TBB=ON -D WITH_EIGEN=OFF -D WITH_V4L=OFF -D WITH_VTK=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/opencv_contrib/modules /opt/opencv/
```

I  get the above error `CMakeLists.txt` does not appear to exist.
What is the solution to this?

Added:I created a new opt folder in home directory which should have been in the root... there was where I made the mistake maybe.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions *correctly* using the same paths and running every command as instructed? Path matters here, so `pwd` should output `/opt/opencv/release`. You did execute `cmake` as root, didn't you? Please answer questions by [edit]ing your post rather than using comments.

Comment: I created a new opt folder in home directory which should have been in the root... there was where I made the mistake maybe

Comment: **Please answer questions by [edit]ing your post rather than using comments.** Please add the steps exactly as you followed them.